# Is the acceleration the quotient of the inner product (of velocity and acceleration) and the speed? Proof

Tags: kinematics

The inner product of acceleration and speed is (the product of) both their moduli times the cosine of the angle between them, which divided by speed leaves the acceleration (modulus) times the cosine. Then the above statement is true only if velocity and acceleration are parallel which is not true in general.

Comment: What you said works for any two parallel vectors. You're just rearranging terms in $\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B} = | \mathbf{A}| |\mathbf{B}|$ when $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are parallel.

Comment: In your first line I think you mean velocity rather than speed.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac1v \left[\vec v .\frac {d \vec v}{dt}\right]=\frac{1}{2v} \left[\frac {d (\vec v.\vec v)}{dt}\right]=\frac{1}{2v} \left[\frac {d (v^2)}{dt}\right]=\frac{1}{2v}2v\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dt}$$
$\frac{dv}{dt}$ is rate of change of speed. This is not the magnitude of the acceleration, unless the body is moving in a constant direction.

But that's just what you are saying! If the body is moving in a constant direction, then we can write $\vec v$ in terms of a constant unit vector $\hat n$:
$$\vec v =v \hat n\ \ \ \ \ \text{so}\ \ \ \ \ \frac{d\vec v}{dt}=\hat n\frac{dv}{dt}$$
in other words $\vec v$ and $\frac{d\vec v}{dt}$ are parallel!

The working at the top uses the identity
$$\frac{d(\vec A.\vec B)}{dt}=\vec A.\frac{d\vec B}{dt}+\vec B.\frac{d\vec A}{dt}$$
This holds whether or not $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ are parallel to each other, as you can show by writing $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ in terms of their cartesian components.